# Nricens - Able to provide p-value?

Tags: r, cox-regression

Attempting to do Net Reclassification Index with nricens package for  comparing coxph model.

Able to get details of NRI - but nil p-value was reported.

```
> nricens(time = dat$DaysDSCtoFOreadmORlastpresc, event = dat$ReAdmFOHosp90D, mdl.std = modelSurvClin90d, mdl.new = modelSurvClinPsySoc90d, cut = c(0.15,0.25), niter = 1000, updown = 'category', t0 = 90)

UP and DOWN calculation:
  #of total, case, and control subjects at t0:  1518 261 1135

  Reclassification Table for all subjects:
         New
Standard  < 0.15 < 0.25 >= 0.25
  < 0.15     649     28       1
  < 0.25      34    547      29
  >= 0.25      0     13     217

  Reclassification Table for case:
         New
Standard  < 0.15 < 0.25 >= 0.25
  < 0.15      66      7       0
  < 0.25       4    106       7
  >= 0.25      0      2      69

  Reclassification Table for control:
         New
Standard  < 0.15 < 0.25 >= 0.25
  < 0.15     536     20       1
  < 0.25      29    391      20
  >= 0.25      0     10     128

NRI estimation by KM estimator:

Point estimates:
                  Estimate
NRI            0.027005665
NRI+           0.029419941
NRI-          -0.002414276
Pr(Up|Case)    0.052036031
Pr(Down|Case)  0.022616090
Pr(Down|Ctrl)  0.032780501
Pr(Up|Ctrl)    0.035194777
```

Any ways of computing the p-value?